# How to change picture in picturebox according to value in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I would like to ask you, how can I change picture in picture box , according to value in combobox. For example, I would like to have picture of "dog" when I choose in combobox "dog", when I change in combobox to "cat" ,in picturebox I will have cat.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the image in picture box according to value in combobox, you can refer to the following code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Image1 path");
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"Image2 path");
        }
    }
```